# display all the files and the directory of the each file under a root folder recursively

Tags: java

i want to display all the files and the directory of each file under a root directory recursively

the output should look like this

filename ---> the directory which contains that file

for example
filename.jpg--->c:\workspace

the filename.jpg is in c:\workspace i.e :the path is c:\workspace\filename.txt there are many files in each directory

Comment: What have you tried? The java.io.File class has everything you need to implement this. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: First google hit [`Recursive File Listing`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that filenames with the same name will be overridden in this solution (you need a `Map<String, List<File>>` to allow this):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, File> map = getFiles(new File("."));

    for (String name : map.keySet())
        if (name.endsWith(".txt")) // display filter
            System.out.println(name + " ---> " + map.get(name));
}

private static Map<String, File> getFiles(File current) {

    Map<String, File> map = new HashMap<String, File>();

    if (current.isDirectory()) { 
        for (File file : current.listFiles()) {
            map.put(file.getName(), current);
            map.putAll(getFiles(file));
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Example output:

```
test1.txt ---> .
test2.txt ---> .\doc
test3.txt ---> .\doc\test
```

Comment: i want to display the files of a particular extension only how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Commons Fileutils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File rootDir = new File("/home/marco/tmp/");
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(rootDir, new String[] {
            "jpeg", "log" }, true);
    for (File file : files) {
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " -> "
                + path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')));
    }
}
```

The first argument of `listFiles` is the directory from which you want to start searching, the second argument is an array of `String`s giving the desired file extensions, and the third argument is a `boolean` saying if the search is recursive or not.

Example output:

```
visicheck.jpeg -> /home/marco/tmp
connettore.jpeg -> /home/marco/tmp
sme2.log -> /home/marco/tmp/sme2_v2_1/log
davmail_smtp.jpeg -> /home/marco/tmp
```